# Swift: Load the SKScene from GameMenu.sks doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

i have the problem, that the GameViewController doesn't load my GameMenu. If i simulate my app it only shows a grey screen with node:0 and the fps count.

Here the Code from GameViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = GameMenu(fileNamed: "GameMenu") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

I tried also the line:

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameMenu")
```

but it changed nothing.

I also added the Custom Class "GameMenu" to the GameMenu.sks

I think the problem is this `if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameMenu")` line.
I have read a lot about this problem but i my case nothing was successful.

I also tried this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let gkScene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameMenu.sks") {

            if let skScene = gkScene.rootNode as? SKScene {
                 // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                skScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(skScene)
            }
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

but nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load it as `GKScene` from `.sks` file and get `SKScene` from its `rootNode` attribute.

```
if let gkScene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameMenu") {
  if let skScene = gkScene.rootNode as? SKScene {
     // TODO
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i get SKScene from its rootNode attribute?

Comment: By casting it to `SKScene` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gkscene/1640947-rootnode). Updated the answer.

Comment: thank you but the solution changes nothing...., I updated my answer and added your solution

Comment: Perhaps you can look what happens inside `override func didMove(to view: SKView)` of `GameMenu`?

Comment: nothing because it failes at this if loop : if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameMenu")

Comment: GKScene you mean?

Comment: yes but it doesn't metter which one, in both cases happends nothing. I have to add some information: I added a new target in my singleview Project and created the game in this new target. No problems. than i wanted to fusion this 2 targets. I added the files of the game target to the single view target per drag and drop. But i think this is not the problem, because i can call the GameViewController and the problem comes with this line i said in the comment before...

Comment: Check in the right pane of Xcode whether `GameMenu.sks` is checked for the correct target.

Comment: try `GKScene(fileNamed: "GameMenu")` (without `.sks`)

Comment: ...share the project, or a part of it on GitHub?

Comment: which part do you think is necessary to find the solution?

Comment: only sks and its loading

Comment: ...or you can try inserting your .sks into a brand new SpriteKit game project and check if it works. Or you can have a look at my sample project here - https://github.com/maxvol/RxSpriteGame